# Read txt file into python

Tags: python

I have german wordlist which contain special charachters like ä,ö,ü. and a word e.g. like "Nährstoffe". But when i read the text file and create a dict from it i get a wrong word out of it.

Here is my code in python3:

```
import random
import csv
import os
permanettxtfile='wortliste.txt'
newlines = open(permanettxtfile, "r")
lines=newlines.read().split('\n')
random.shuffle(lines)

linkdict=dict.fromkeys(lines)
print(linkdict)
```

I get as output:

```
'NÃ¤hrstoffe': None
```

But i want:

```
'Nährstoffe': None
```

How can i solve this issue? Is this an UTF-8 issue?

Comment: BTW, encoding is complicated. The answers on the linked questions will probably solve the problem, but just in case they don't, you'll want to check what encoding the file is saved as (with a utility like `file` on Unix/Linux for example), the default encoding Python is detecting (`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`), and what encoding your terminal/console is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening file in `utf-8` encoding:

```py
import random
import csv
import os

permanettxtfile='wortliste.txt'

with open(permanettxtfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')
    random.shuffle(lines)

linkdict = dict.fromkeys(lines)
print(linkdict)
```

Also don't forget to close it with context manager as in my example or with `newlines.close()` for your example

Answer (score 0):

Specify the encoding using

```
open(permanettxtfile, "r", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likly a encoding issue you can try this:

```
with open("filename.txt", "rb") as f:
     contents = f.read().decode("UTF-8")
```

or

```
 with open("filename.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
      contents = f.read()
```